# How to make TensorProduct distributive?

Tags: tensors

Usually the tensorproduct is distributive:

$A\otimes(B+C) = A\otimes B+A\otimes C$

But the Mathematica function TensorProduct does not seem to have this property. Both

```
TensorExpand[A \[CircleTimes] (B + C)]
```

and

```
Simplify[A \[CircleTimes] B + A \[CircleTimes] C]
```

just return their argument.

Is there a way so Mathematica simplifies or expands such expressions?

Comment: Use `\[TensorProduct]` instead of `\[CircleTimes]`

Comment: Huh, both have the same symbol. How unfortunate.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Not the same symbol, just one that looks exactly the same

Comment: @lennart it works for me

Comment: Okay TensorExpand works now indeed! Any chance of also making Simplify or Collect work with TensorProduct?

Comment: @lennart best to make this a new question